# Introducing Serializable to Existing Code

Tags: java

I believe this should be a really common case, yet I can't find any best practices. Assume I have the following class:

```
public class Equation {

    private Operator operator;
    private Object leftValue;
    private Object rightValue;

    // getters and setters
}

public enum Operator  {...}
```

This class has been with us for some years already and is well used. Now I need to make it serializable. How do I do that?

**Just add `implements Serializable`**

In that case, the `Equation` class only works as long as the values are `Serializable`. Since equations only really work on numbers (maybe dates and strings?) that might work. But the values could be any kind of `Object`, so there has to be a better way.

**Make values `Serializable`**

```
public class Equation implements Serializable{

    private Operator operator;
    private Serializable leftValue;
    private Serializable rightValue;

    // getters and setters 
}
```

This works in any case, but these changes are an API break. And no matter what I do I need to change all the code using the class, which leads to potentially even more API breaks. For a big software system that might take ages.

**Make values `Serializable`, leave getters and setters as is**

```
public void setLeftValue(Object leftValue) {
    if (!(leftValue instanceof Serializable)) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be Serializable!");
    this.leftValue = leftValue;
}
```

This code breaks no existing API, but changes how the code behaves. Yet if I assume that all the values are `Serializable` anyways, I feel like this might be the way to go. I can even put the new setters next to the old ones and deprecated them to make it obvious to future developers what objects to use.

**Make values `transient`:**

At least that's what Sonar suggests. Yet it leads to an unusable class, at least in all the cases where we actually need `Equation` to be `Serializable`.

**Create implementation that is `Serializable`:**

```
public class SerializableEquation extends Equation implements Serializable{

    private Serializable leftValue;
    private Serializable rightValue;

    // override getters and setters
}
```

That way we would have to use an entire different class for serialization purposes, which seems kind of ugly, doesn't it?

**Question:**

What is a good way to handle this use case? I ideally don't want to break the API. And seeing as Java has yet to break the API there must be a way to handle cases like this.

Comment: This is clearly a problem of implementation, there should be a `Operand` class /interface instead of `Object`. In that case, you would only had to add the implementation to that class/interface.

Comment: Your question shows the disadvantage of Java's built-in serialization mechanism. Is it really necessary to make the classes serializable? Or could you find some other solution, for example write classes that can read / write `Equation` objects in a standard format such as XML or JSON.

Comment: Implement Serializable. Document that an equation can only be serializable if its values also are (although that should be obvious). ArrayList stores any kind of Object, and still implements Serializable. You shouldn't fear doing the same thing.

Comment: @AxelH Wouldn't that just move the problem to the `Operand` class? Because to make it compatible it would have to have the `Object` field, too. And I'm not sure if adding a `Serializable` to an interface where you don't control all the implementations is that a good idea.

Comment: @Jesper Sadly it is in this case, since it's for RMI.

Comment: "Just add `implements Serializable`. In that case, the `Equation` class only works as long as the values are `Serializable`." => The `Equation` class will continue _working_ as expected even without serializable values. It cannot be _serialized_, though, which is exactly what you want. It seems that it's enough to have your  `class Equation implements Serializable`. Oh, and don't forget to specify a `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: No, because this should be manage in OO, one implementation for NumericalOperand, one for FunctionOperand (just example ;) ), all of those implementing the Operand and Serializable. This should have been implemented to manage every case with specific Class and not just using an Object. With this, you can maintain your code easily. EDIT: from the beginning, you said the one object can be in a equation, so this could take anyting, own do you multiply two `UrlConnection` ?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, I would add a methods to check if this `Equation` is correctly serializable then (checking the type of both values).

Comment: @AxelH Then you'd either have an `Operand` that is not `Serializable`, which leads to the same warning about unserializable fields this question is about. Or you implement  `Serializable` with your `Operand` interface, which means there are implementations of  `Operand` that never knew they should be `Serializable` and hence are probably not.

Comment: @AxelH Where? When? At setter time? I would argue against that! As OP explained that would break behavior. So, simply let an `Equation` object work with non-serializable values, but let it throw an exception when actually serializing. That way, the `Equation` can be serialized with serializable values. It's up to the usage of the class.

Comment: @JBNizet If it really is that easy then that's the answer, I guess.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, using the setter will restraint the code but with a check method call before the serialisation is used will prevent that this will not work correctly.

Comment: If you really need to take on the complete control on what to seralize and what not to, you can go for **Externalization**. In this mechanism, only identity of the class is written in the serialization stream and it is the responsibility of the class to save and restore the contents of its instances.

Comment: @AxelH You already have such a constraint check _built in_: You will get a  [`java.io.NotSerializableException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) in that case. No need to implement that check on your own.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes, you are right, if you prefer to use exceptions. But I found that cleaner to provide a methods to check that. Between a simple `if` and a `try-catch`, I prefer the `if` ;) but of course, this could be to the serialize method signature to inform the devs that this could happen.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of problem, a correct implementation should have used interfaces to limit the field of action.

What is the point the add an `UrlConnection` to a `String` ? Well, this should have been something like this :

```
public class Equation {
    Operator operator;
    Operand leftOp, rightOp;

    ...
}

interface Operand {

    ...
}
```

And then, for specific type of data, you would have implements specific classs

```
public IntegerOperand implements Operand {

    public Integer value;
    ...
}
```

From this, you only need to add the Serialiszable to `Operator` and `Operand`. This will be a contract that the dev need to follow, so every implementation need to be serializable (fully serializable since the interface asked it), this will be easy to test with JUnit.

## But

In you case, you can't update the code because this would break the compatibility. So I would put the serialisation to the test, meaning that I woulld check if both Object instance ARE serializable, if not, then you do what you want with it.

You, either, check that with a method when you want (before serialisation) to prevent that this action can't be done with this data or with the setter of both value to restraint the possibilities.

```
public boolean isSerialisable(){ 
    return Serializable.class.isAssignable(leftValue.class)
            && Serializable.class.isAssignable(rightValue.class);
}
```

This will be call before you need to serialize the instance, as a warning or error. (or directly in the setters if you want to break everything ;) )

Last resort, you serialize yourself the data, you can use some library to generate different type of structure, XML, JSON, .. or probably in bytes directly (no example in mind)

## EDIT:

Here is a quick (and ugly example) of serialisation with Object

```
public class Main implements Serializable{

    public Object value;

    public Main(Object o){ this.value = o; }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main m = new Main(new A());

        try {
             FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
             out.writeObject(m);
             out.close();
             fileOut.close();
        }catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

        m = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("test.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            m = (Main) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(Exception i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(" M : " + m);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value == null ? "null" : value.toString();
    }

    static class A implements Serializable{
        String s = "foo";

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

By removing the implementation if `serializable` from `A`, this will failed. But like this, we see that this is working like expected.

Comment: Why does the interface have fields? And how do you justify an interface for an POJO? And how does that prevent me from creating a class `class ObjectOperand implements Operand { public Object value; }` and breaking the implementation in exactly the same way the original code would?

Comment: @SteffiS. Sorry, the interface is a mistake ... this should be a class (editing). If Operand is Serializable, ObjectOperand should be. If one of your implementation is not correctly implemented, you break the contract of the Operand interface that ask to be Serializable ;)

Comment: I actually don't understand how that helps me with my problem. Even if I had the `Operand` interface (which I don't)... making it `Serializable` would break the code in exactly the same way it does when I add it to my current code.

Comment: @SteffiS. This would not break anything to add an interface that doesn't needs any implementation. The first part of the answer is how it should have be done to be more documented, to be sure that you don't put anything into your `Object`.  You can add the interface to `Equation` without breaking anything, this will not work if the instance doesn't implements Serializable but this won't break the actual code ...

Comment: Yes, it will break. If I use `Object`s in the implementation of `Operand` then the `Equation` class will not be `Serializable` as well. If I only use `Integer` or other serializable classes, then it works of course, but then it works in my above code as well. I just don't see the merit.

Comment: @SteffiS. like I said, the first part is just for information, this would have help to track what can be use in `Equation` meaning to check if everything you can use is `Serializable`, Object is too broad. In your case, if you just add the interface, this will NOT break until you try to serialize. This is why the second part of the answer is here, you need to check if both instance are Serialisable before (or catching the exception). But in anycase, adding the interface will generate any compilation error. Only Serialization would, but you don't have any since you are only adding it NOW.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128680/discussion-between-axelh-and-steffi-s).

Comment: @SteffiS. See my example that I've just added. This is a working code that can be use to do some test, you will see that even if you use `Object`, this is the instance type at runtime that is important, so this will only fail if the instance are not serializable. Only need one check before you serialize your instance to prevent any problem